# Find the latest streak

Tags: sql, sqlite, gaps-and-islands

I would like to create an SQlite query to find streaks from a specific date.

I have the table:

| id | dt |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10/12/2023 |
| 2 | 11/12/2023 |
| 3 | 12/12/2023 |
| 4 | 16/12/2023 |
| 5 | 17/12/2023 |
| 6 | 25/12/2023 |
| 7 | 26/12/2023 |

For example, if I query the data for:

- `09/12/2023` - the result will be `0`
- `12/12/2023` - the result will be `3`
- `11/12/2023` - the result will be `2`
- `17/12/2023` - the result will be `2`
- `24/12/2023` - the result will be `0`
- `26/12/2023` - the result will be `2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a *gaps and islands* problem. To solve it we need to enumerate each successive group of rows by a unique id.

We can use the window function `LAG()` to get the previous row and calculate the difference between successive dates and then apply a running total to the resulting differences:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
         CASE WHEN julianday(dt)-julianday(LAG(dt, 1, dt) OVER (ORDER BY dt)) <= 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS date_diff
  FROM mytable
  WHERE dt <= '2023-12-26'
),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT *, SUM(date_diff) OVER (ORDER BY dt) as grp
  FROM cte
)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM cte2 c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(grp) as latest_grp, MAX(dt) as latest_dt
  FROM cte2
) AS s ON s.latest_grp = c.grp AND s.latest_dt = '2023-12-26'
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ir-R2zol)

Comment: Thank you very much! It works exactly as expected.

Comment: how should I modify the query if my dates are stored not as strings but as integer values with an amount of seconds?

Comment: You can do something like this : https://dbfiddle.uk/uz1nz7Ar

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT dt, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d', dt) ORDER BY dt) AS grp
    FROM your_table_name
)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN dt <= 'your_specific_date' THEN grp ELSE 0 END) as streak
FROM cte;
```

Replace `your_table_name` with the actual table name and `'your_specific_date'` with the specific date you want to query.

Comment: Thanks @larry-neil for your answer, but it seems that the provided query works a bit differently. When I execute it for `11/12/2023` or for `12/12/2023`, I would expect `2` and `3`.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please try again with it.

Comment: The new query works as expected for `11/12/2023` and `12/12/2023` but not for `17/12/2023`,  `24/12/2023` etc...   There should not be a streak if there is a gap of 1 day or more between dates.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please try again.

Comment: Now it always returns 0 for any date :(

Comment: I updated my answer. Try again and let me know if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately no. It still returns 0